# Convert multiple colums from Excel number to date format

Tags: r, date, format, multiple-columns

I downloaded an Excel file with 200+ columns. Some are character, some numeric and other date format. The date columns are downloaded in R as an Excel number format like "42369" "43380".

| B_1 | B_2 | B_Date_1 | B_Date_2 | V_1 | V-2 | V_3 | Z_1 | Z_2 | Z_3 | V_Date_1 | V_Date_2 | V_Date_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | qsdsq | 42369 | 43380 | 5.6 | 7.2 | 2.3 | dsff | fdgsfd | fdgs | 42370 | 42380 | 42369 |
| afdf | dsqfs | 42452 | 43383 | 5.1 | 2.8 | 3.7 | hgfj | azer | NULL | 42370 | 42380 | 42369 |

I found the

> excel_numeric_to_date()

command from the library(janitor) to convert one date column from Excel number to date format.

> df$B_Date_1  <- as.numeric(df$B_Date_1)
> df$B_Date_1 <- excel_numeric_to_date(df$B_Date_1)

I would like to repeat this command for all the date columns (there are many). I selected the column names

> select = c(B_Date_1:B_Date2,V_Date_1:V_Date_2)

and tried various approaches with lapply()or with mutate() like

```
df %>% mutate(across(subset(select = c(B_Date_1:B_Date_2,V_Date_1:V_Date_3)),
       as.numeric())) %>% 
       excel_numeric_to_date()
```

But could not find any solution to convert all the excel number date column into a Date format column in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(B_Date_1:B_Date_2,V_Date_1:V_Date_3), excel_numeric_to_date))
```

That returns

```
   B_1   B_2   B_Date_1   B_Date_2 V_1 V.2 V_3  Z_1    Z_2  Z_3   V_Date_1   V_Date_2
1 NULL qsdsq 2015-12-31 2018-10-07 5.6 7.2 2.3 dsff fdgsfd fdgs 2016-01-01 2016-01-11
2 afdf dsqfs 2016-03-23 2018-10-10 5.1 2.8 3.7 hgfj   azer NULL 2016-01-01 2016-01-11
    V_Date_3
1 2015-12-31
2 2015-12-31
```

If you want all columsn with the word "Date" in them, you could also do

```
df %>% mutate(across(contains("Date"), excel_numeric_to_date))
```